# Can I use backup/restore to move a database created with EF Code First?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an application that uses EF Code First against a SQL Server 2012 database. I'm using the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer.

I have a database on my development machine that I want to move over to my testing machine, and to do that I'm attempting to use backup/restore. Unfortunately, having done that, I get the dreaded "Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata" error.

I don't understand why this is the case - the database works OK on my dev machine. Is it not possible to transfer the database to another machine?

Comment: What EF version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: the issue was that the __MigrationHistory table, while present, was not accessible to the application because of insufficient database privileges. I (temporarily) made the user a DBO on the database, and it all worked fine. (Hat tip to Jayantha).

Answer (score 1):

Now the metadata table is removed from the code first DB and added the `__MigrationHistory`  table to system tables. You can try running `Enable-Migrations` command in Package Manager Console. [Here is more details](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/01/13/ef-4-3-beta-1-what-happened-to-that-edmmetadata-table/) .

Comment: Thanks. Since the table was actually part of the database, it was moved over with the rest of my database. The issue was that my code was running in the context of a user that did not have access to the system tables, hence the error. +1 for the tip.